# Overwriting “ArcGIS Online World Geocoding service” on search widget?

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, mapserver, search, geocoding-service

I am new and just exploring ArcGIS API

Wondering how to overwrite the default "ArcGIS Online World Geocoding service" each time i search it calls that service.

I wanted to call our own geocoding service. to add up. I can't also call my MapServer query using the sandbox using the search widget, but the sample 'Query' sandbox can call our MapServer.

Is there any important thing i missed like set-up on our ArcGIS server for the search functionalities to function?

Comment: What "ArcGIS API" are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the JS API, you can override the locator used in the search widget/dijit by specifying a search source. There is a a sample in the online docs at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/search_customlocator.html, but the pertinent info is

```
    var search = new Search({
    sources: [{
        //Pass in the custom locator to the sources
        locator: new Locator(locatorUrl),
        singleLineFieldName: "AssetID",
        outFields: ["Match_addr"],
        name: "HBR_Asset",
        placeholder: "H-L-N-EW-090-GLO-001-403-OWT",
        highlightSymbol: new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/dijit/Search/images/search-pointer.png", 36, 36).setOffset(9, 18),
        //Create an InfoTemplate
        infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Asset ID", "ID: ${Match_addr}")
    }],
    map: map,
    enableSearchingAll: false,
    autoComplete: true,
    value: "H-L-N-EW-090-GLO-001-403-OWT"
}, "search");

search.startup();
```